# How to open my website with secure http (https)?

Tags: http, https, web

The company I'm working for has a PC for hosting our website. I can access the website with http without any problem but when I add https it gives me this error. We are using apache for our web server (XAMPP).

*Object not found!*

*The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.*

*If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.*

*Error 404*

However when I try to copy the website to my other computer (also with XAMPP on it) and run the website in localhost with https its working fine. I tried to look for answer but I can't seem to find the one that I'm looking for. Does anyone have encountered this problem or know what may have caused this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The likely explanation is that the Apache server on your "other computer" has the HTTPS port open, whereas it is closed on your first computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. It was because the DocumentRoot directory and Servername in http-ssl.conf in apache/conf/extra folder was still set on default. I changed it so it uses the same servername and documentroot directory that I had specified in httpd-vhosts.conf

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue on LAMP server. In the ssl.conf file we changed AllowOverride None for ;  to AllowOverride All. That corrected the problem.

DocumentRoot /var/www/

< Directory />

Options FollowSymLinks

AllowOverride None

< /Directory>

< Directory /var/www/>

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

AllowOverride All

Order allow,deny

allow from all

< /Directory>